# Chart bar with codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create a chart with the chart bar and list all the new records that I added in my database and get the month it was added.

The problem is my application is in php and I saw that chart.js is in javascript.

[image]

This is the html of my chart that is in index.php

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <!-- Bar Chart -->
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>GuiaCorretor - Analitycs</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <canvas id="bar_chart" height="50"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #END# Bar Chart -->
</div>
```

And this is the code that is in my javascript, but here there is no link to my database, how could I sync my javascript and get this information?

```
    $(function () {
    //new Chart(document.getElementById("line_chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('line'));
    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar_chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('bar'));
    //new Chart(document.getElementById("radar_chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('radar'));
    //new Chart(document.getElementById("pie_chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('pie'));
});

function getChartJs(type) {
    var config = null;

    if (type === 'bar') {
        config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["JANEIRO", "FEVEREIRO", "MARÇO", "ABRIL", "MAIO", "JUNHO", "JULHO", "AGOSTO", "SETEMBRO", "OUTUBRO", "NOVEMBRO", "DEZEMBRO"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Imóveis cadastrados",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.8)'
                }, {
                        label: "Imóveis cadastrados",
                        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.8)'
                    }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: false
            }
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use your controller to create the data in an array format, and pass that data into your view as a json string.

In php create the data array that .js needs:

```
$chartData = [
    'labels' => ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', ...], 
    'datasets' => [ 
        [
            'label' => "Imóveis cadastrados",
            'data' => [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            'backgroundColor' => 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.8)'
        ], 
        [...] 
    ] 
];
```

Then json_encode that data as a data attribute of your canvas (the syntax here will vary depending on what method you use to pass dynamic data into your view, I will use raw PHP here for demonstration):

`<canvas id="bar_chart" height="50" data-chart-data="<?php json_encode($chartData); ?>"></canvas>`

And then lastly use the json contained in that data attribute to power your chart:

```
config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: document.getElementById("bar_chart").data('chart-data'),
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: false
            }
        }
```

Comment: But how would I make the connection to my database?

Comment: How do you currently connect to your database?

Comment: I use framework codeigniter and my database this in config/database

Comment: Access your database normally in your controller when you build the $chartData variable in my example.